# Linear Algebra, Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors Exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question from an exercise. I am given a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with 2 dimensions and I am asked to find a basis of eigenvectors. I found the eigenvalues but I have noticed whenever I tried to find the eigenvectors I would have a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, generally finding $\ker\left(xI-\left[T\right]_{B^{'}}\right)$ would give me the eigenvectors . So I didn't know how to solve it and this was the solution. Can someone explain me why the linear combinations are giving me here the eigenvectors at the end?
Thank you!

Question:Let there be the vector space;

$V=\left\{ \left[\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{array}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^{3}|x+y+z=0\right\} $

and the linear transformation

$T\left[\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
3x+3y-3z\\
4x-2y+4z\\
-x+5y+5z
\end{array}\right]$

Find basis B
  of eigenvector and write $\left[T\right]_{B}$

Solution

We will chose arbitrary basis to calculate the eigenvalues.

$B^{'}=\left[\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1\\
0
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
-1
\end{array}\right]\right]$

Then $\left[T\right]_{B^{'}}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-6 & 0\\
6 & 6
\end{array}\right]$

$\det\left|xI-\left[T\right]_{B^{'}}\right|=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
x+6 & 0\\
-6 & x-6
\end{array}\right]=\left(x-6\right)\left(x+6\right)$

The eigenvalues are x=6
  and x=-6

$x=6\Rightarrow \ker\left(6I-\left[T\right]_{B^{'}}\right)=\operatorname{span}\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1
\end{array}\right]\right)$

$x=-6\Rightarrow \ker\left(-6I-\left[T\right]_{B^{'}}\right)=\operatorname{span}\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
-2\\
1
\end{array}\right]\right)$

Then our basis $B=\left(u_{1},u_{2}\right)$
  of eigenvector are

$\begin{cases}
u_{1}=0v_{1}+v_{2}\\
u_{2}=-2v_{1}+v_{2}
\end{cases}\Rightarrow\left[\begin{array}{cc}
6 & 0\\
0 & -6
\end{array}\right]$

Comment: You're working this fine, up to the last steps.  An eigenvector for $x=6$ is given by $0b_1+1b_2$, and an eigenvector for $x=-6$ is given by $-2b_1+1b_2$, where $b_1$ and $b_2$ are the basis vectors you chose for V.

Comment: Firsly, thanks for the feedback!

Yes but the part that I don't understand is, ker(tI-A) has to give me the eigenvectors (where t=6 or t=-6), however since my vector space is two dimensonal and I am working with vector in $R^3$, it gives me a vector in $R^2$ .And that can't be the eigenvectors since I am working in a vector space where the vectors are elements of $R^3$. So I am confused why would the linear combinations give me the eigenvectors?

Comment: Try think in following way. You make an isomorphism between your two dimensional vector space and $R^2$. You solve your problem in $R^2$, then you should come back.

Comment: I got it! Thanks! I've sat for along time thinking why this is true now I get it!